# vector of pointers resize

Tags: c++, vector, resize, smart-pointers

While writing on my CFD-Code I had a problem with a vector of pointer.
I broke it down to the following code, which represents the core problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class MyClass{
    public:
        MyClass()                               {}
        MyClass(int i)                          {_myVec.push_back(i);}
        ~MyClass()                              {_myVec.clear();}
        const std::vector<int> myVec() const    {return _myVec;}
        std::vector<int> _myVec;
    private:
};


int main(){
    std::size_t size = 3;
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<MyClass> > myClass;
    // add some elements with push_back
    for(auto i = 0; i < size; i++){
        myClass.push_back(std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass()));
    }
    for(auto i = 0; i < size; i++){
        myClass[i]->_myVec.push_back(i);
    }
    // print
    for(auto i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(auto j = 0; j < myClass[i]->myVec().size(); j++){
            std::cout << myClass[i]->myVec()[j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    myClass.clear();


    // add some elements with resize
    myClass.resize(size, std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass()));
    for(auto i = 0; i < size; i++){
        myClass[i]->_myVec.push_back(i);
    }
    //print 
    for(auto i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(auto j = 0; j < myClass[i]->myVec().size(); j++){
            std::cout << myClass[i]->myVec()[j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    myClass.clear();
}
```

The ouput for this piece of code is the following.

```
0
1
2

0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
```

The first part is just what I expect. The second part was, what surprised me. The resize function obviously first builds the class and than referes all pointers in the vector to this one class instead of what I thought the vector::resize would do, namely calling the new operator for every element, so that every element in vector would point to its own object. I don't really find this behaviour intuitive and logical, if I wanted to have the same pointer on every vector element, I would tell the compiler so by writing like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> myTempclass = std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass())
for(auto i = 0; i < size; i++){
    myClass.push_back(myTempclass);
}
```

Could somebody please explain why the vector behaves like that in this particular situation, or has a link to a good site (the c++ reference sites didn't help me to explain it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The resize function obviously first builds the class and than referes all pointers in the vector to this one class

Actually no, that's not quite what happened. *You* built the class (and shared pointer) when you wrote `std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass())` in the call. resize just takes the resulting parameter and does its logic with that.

resize's logic is to create any necessary new values by *copying* the parameter. Copying a shared_ptr creates new pointer objects which point to the same thing. So that leads to the result you see.

It's as if you had written:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr(new MyClass());
for(auto i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    myClass.push_back(ptr);
}
```

Comment: So do I get it right when I say that the resize operator can copy one and only one value(class, pointer etc.) to all elements in the vector? That makes the function much less flexible than I thought it would be.

Comment: Yeah, to all elements that it needs to create. It was probably intended more for cases where the vector contains objects directly, such as `std::vector<MyClass>`